# Disable Fabric UI JS Dialog Auto-Refresh

Tags: modal-dialog, fabric, office-ui-fabric

I am using the Fabric UI JS components on a SharePoint 2016 project (not using React or SharePoint Framework) and having issues with the dialog box buttons refreshing the page upon click.

Reviewing [Microsoft's documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric-js/components/dialog/dialog) and removing their "Wire up the buttons" and actionHandler functions, I tried using a simple:

```
$(document).on('click', '[id=btnName]', function() {

    callingFunction();
});

function callingFunction() {

     console.log("Entered callingFunction");

     // Do more stuff

}
```

In my console, I am seeing "Entered callingFunction," but then it immediately navigates to the original page, instead of performing the tasks I have in "Do more stuff". How do I prevent the page refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I simply needed to use the documentation as provided and then use e.preventDefault(); to prevent the page from refreshing.

```
   // Wire up the buttons
    for (var i = 0; i < actionButtonElements.length; i++) {
      actionButtonComponents[i] = new fabric['Button'](actionButtonElements[i], actionHandler);

    }
    // When clicking the button, open the dialog
    button.onclick = function() {
      openDialog(dialog);
    };

    function actionHandler(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      if(this.innerText.trim() == "Save") {

            runSave();

      } else if (this.innerText.trim() == "Cancel" {
            dialogComponent.close();
      }

    }
```